# node.js game example only works on my computer

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using this game example: https://github.com/robhawkes/mozilla-festival

I have this exactly as it is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\games\websockets

and I am running 'node game.js' with the game.js file located alongside the public folder.

I'm running the server on port 80 with Apache.

Currently it only works when I connect to it from my computer(creates a player each time I open it in a new window). But when I try to connect to it from another computer, it gives me these errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js

Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Game on my website: http://123testing.no-ip.biz/games/websockets/public/

Am I missing something?
Sorry if this is a really silly question!

EDIT: got it working! Thanks, Louis and SVN, you're both great. The final problem was that in my game.js it was connecting to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hardcoded the server address in your HTML:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Remove the server address from it, like you do for your other scripts. Either this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Or this would work:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

depending on where the script is physically located on your server. I'm thinking the 2nd is probably what you want, but I'm not sure because I see evidence of both being possible.

(ETA: Having "localhost" as a server address to load resources in HTML which is meant to be loaded by the general public is definitely wrong. Unfortunately, there's something else going on with your server setup that I can't diagnose.)

Comment: What do you mean by hardcoded? How would I go about making it relative?

Comment: Okay I replaced it with /socket.io/socket.io.js and now it says: GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/?t=15349081350913

Comment: Try the 2nd example I gave, without a leading slash.

Comment: I tried without a leading slash and now it doesn't work on either computer giving the same error: GET http://123testing.no-ip.biz/games/websockets/public/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (not found) and Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

Comment: The proper usage is <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>, now the client sents a socket.io connect request with a token to the server, but the server is not responding to that, i think it has got something to do with the way you've set up your server for outside access.

If you want to access it publicly via a public ip, you need to make sure, that your port is forwarded.  hope that helps.

Comment: Both ports 80 and 8000 are forwarded. Still gives the error GET localhost:8000/socket.io/1/?t=123somelongnumber123

Comment: Might there be something from with  socket = io.connect("http://localhost", {port: 8000, transports: ["websocket"]});  in game.js?

Comment: @user3050748 I'm looking at the original game.js code. The author there was **listening** to connections (i.e. server end). However, you use ``io.connect`` is for the *client* end of a connection.